# How can I merge time series data from 2 different csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-processing

I have 2 csv files, the first one contains timestamp of event. I want to add weather details from the 2nd csv file.

File 1 (irregular time stamps)

```
Time                        UserID_Detected             
2019-01-01 01:00:32          3                     
2019-01-02 06:02:12          2               
2019-01-02 14:45:32          7
```

File 2 (hourly weather)

```
Time                        Temperature  Humidity
1/1/2019   0:00             32            55        
1/1/2019   1:00             33            60  
1/1/2019   2:00             33            53    
.............
1/2/2019   6:00             35            58
.............
1/2/2019   15:00            38            62
```

I want to attach the weather variable to the first file. Since the first file contains minutes and second info, I will round to nearest hour. Expected output:

File 1 (final output)

```
Time                        UserID_Detected      Temperature     Humidity       
2019-01-01 01:00:32          3                     33             60
2019-01-02 06:02:12          2                     35             58
2019-01-02 14:45:32          7                     38             62
```

Tried so far:

```
df_event = pd.read_csv("df1.csv") 
df_weather = pd.read_csv("df2.csv") 


df_event ['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_event['Time']) 
df_weather ['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather['Time'])

df_event = df_event .set_index('Time')
df_weather = df_weather .set_index('Time')

df_event = pd.merge(df_event ,df_weather , how='outer',left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: You can use join method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237398/1100913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction=nearest` to merge the two dataframes on the column `Time`:

```
df_event['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_event['Time'])
df_weather['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather['Time'])

df_merged = pd.merge_asof(
    df_event.sort_values(by='Time'), df_weather.sort_values(by='Time'),
    on='Time', direction='nearest')
```

Result:

```
# print(df_merged)

                 Time  UserID_Detected  Temperature  Humidity
0 2019-01-01 01:00:32                3           33        60
1 2019-01-02 06:02:12                2           35        58
2 2019-01-02 14:45:32                7           38        62
```