# Dataframe - interpolate values based on inputs from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, cubic-spline

Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ('2020-09-24','2020-10-19','2020-12-17','2021-03-17','2021-06-17','2021-09-17','2022-03-17','2022-09-20','2023-09-19','2024-09-17','2025-09-17','2026-09-17','2027-09-17','2028-09-19','2029-09-18','2030-09-17','2031-09-17','2032-09-17','2035-09-18','2040-09-18','2045-09-19')
factors = ('1','0.999994','0.999875','1.000166','1.000303','1.000438','1.00056','1.000817','1.001046','1.001412','1.001525','1.001334','1.000685','0.999376','0.997456','0.994626','0.991244','0.986754','0.982072','0.962028','0.925136')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dates']=dates
df['factors']=factors
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df.set_index(['dates'],inplace=True)
df
```

Here is another dataframe with a timeseries with fixed interval

```
interpolated = pd.DataFrame(0, index=pd.date_range('2020-09-24', '2045-09-19', freq='3M'),columns=['result'])
```

The goal is to populate the second dataframe with the cubic spline interpolated values from the first table.
Thanks for all the ideas

Attempt

```
interpolated['result'] = df['factors'].interpolate(method='cubic')
```

However it gives only NaN values in the intepolated dataframe. Not sure how to correctly refer to the first table.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: @ApplePie I did try 
interpolated['result'] = df['factors'].interpolate(method='cubic')

Comment: It would be helpful if you were explain whats going wrong. Is there an error message?

Comment: @ItsAnApe, I have update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, the shapes don't match.  Since it seems none of the dates in the index from the df match the dates in interpolated, you just end up with NaN being filled in on the dates.  I think you want something more like merge or join, as described in this post: [Merging time series data by timestamp using numpy/pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215024/merging-time-series-data-by-timestamp-using-numpy-pandas)
[merge](http://%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge)
and [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) will also be helpful.

Comment: this is the challenge here. Something that can be easily done in Excel I struggle here. The thing is that the dates probably will not match. The idea is to populate the timeseries with the interpolated values for the new dates.

Comment: Then I think you still want a join on the time series, and after that you call interpolate on the data with lots of NaN. Right now you're interpolating on data that is already complete.  I think if you look at the result of your interpolate call, it ought to be identical to your original data.